# Using Terraform. Do azurerm_autoscale_setting or azurerm_monitor_autoscale_setting have memory metric

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure, azure-vm-scale-set

I am using terraform to create autoscale settings for VMs. I am able to add rules for autoscale based on CPU percentage metric:

```
    rule {
            metric_trigger {
                operator           = "GreaterThan"
                threshold          = 50
                time_grain         = "PT1M"
                statistic          = "Average"
                time_window        = "PT5M"
                metric_name        = "Percentage CPU"
                time_aggregation   = "Average"
            }
     }
```

However, I am not able to find how to add rules based on memory percentage utilization. Has anyone done something similar like this? I am even not able to see whether this is supported by the provider: [resource_arm_autoscale_setting](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/blob/master/azurerm/resource_arm_autoscale_setting.go)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could not create it since memory consumption is not available in built-in [host metrics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/virtual-machine-scale-sets-autoscale-overview#use-host-based-metrics) from your VM instances. To create autoscale rules that use more detailed performance metrics, you can install and configure the [Azure diagnostics extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/virtual-machine-scale-sets-autoscale-overview#in-guest-vm-metrics-with-the-azure-diagnostics-extension) on VM instances.

You could see the [Guest OS metrics Resource Manager-based Windows VMs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/autoscale-common-metrics#guest-os-metrics-resource-manager-based-windows-vms)
[image]
For more references:

- [Tutorial: Automatically scale a virtual machine scale set with Azure
  PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/tutorial-autoscale-powershell)
- [Tutorial: Automatically scale a virtual machine scale set with an Azure template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/tutorial-autoscale-template)
- [Send guest OS metrics to the Azure Monitor metric store by using an Azure Resource Manager template for a Windows virtual machine scale set](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/collect-custom-metrics-guestos-resource-manager-vmss)